# C++20: Ranges and Coroutines on Embedded

Tags: c++, gcc, stm32, c++20

I'm trying to get my head around the new C++20 ranges library and coroutines.

In particular, I would like to understand whether we can use those on a bare-metal Embedded platform, let's say STM32. It boils down to these three questions, basically:

1. Do coroutines depend on any OS feature?
2. Are coroutines needed for using the ranges library, e.g. iota()?
3. Does the range library rely on heap allocations?

thanks,
Steffen

Comment: Ad 2. No. Initially ranges was implemented as [3rd party library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) using C++14, since idea is great it was incorporated into C++20 standard (same applies to format which was fmt library).

Comment: Are you asking about any particular existing implementation, or about how to write your own implementation, or something else?

Comment: `How are coroutines implemented` https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/16e2427f50c208dfe07d07f18009969502c25dc8/gcc/coroutine-passes.cc#L88 Why do you care how it's implemented?

Comment: Does it matter how it's implemented if there exists a compliant implementation for the platform you are interested in?

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far! To clarify, I'm not trying to reimplement any of this but trying to understand whether I can afford to use these two features on an STM32 microcontroller.

Comment: @Steffen The best way to see if it meets your needs, as opposed to claims of support is to try it in your environment. Coroutines were designed to allow thread like behavior in a single thread -- if needed. Think of Multix, it is context switching within a thread. I would imagine it would do well in that environment if implementations are performant.  As I don't have access to that environment, I'm not able to test myself. If you are interested, but not urgently, it might pay to wait for c++23, as they are supposed to be fleshed out more and you might find some of it is very applicable.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum That's good advice. I will definitely try coroutines on an eval board.